# Android studio location permission issue

Tags: java, android

I made an android application.

I have problem when starting the app because of location permission, when app start I put function to get device location. The problem is sometime when we click "Yes" on the permission it crashed on the first time. It still get the location and have no problem for second and afterwards.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

do you just ask for permission or do you also search for location data?

Here is an example of a request for permission without seeking the location.

```
if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

return true

}
else{

return false

}
```